# Select only the X Error Bars in Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format the error bars in VBA for Excel.  When I record a macro and click on the Error Bar, I get this as my output:

`ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).ErrorBars.Select`

Thing is, it defaults to the Y error bar when I need the X error bar.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/errorbars-object-excel
Only series in scatter groups can have x and y error bars. This object isn't a collection. There's no object that represents a single error bar; you either have x error bars or y error bars turned on for all points in a series or you have them turned off.

The ErrorBar method changes the error bar format and type.

and then also
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/series-errorbar-method-excel
for  Direction:=xlY

Comment: It's weird though, because you can, for instance, manually color one error bar (X) and another error bar (Y) different colors and it works fine.  One would think it has some means to know X from Y in that case.

Comment: Have you tried using ErrorBar method to change the default?

Comment: Yes.  It changes both the Y bar, but I am having trouble having it set the X bar.  When I run the command in my question above, it just select ErrorBar Y.

Comment: Oops, above should be  for Direction:=xlX  Would that make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a ***severe weakness*** in the VBA Object Model. The X and Y error bars cannot be individually selected or individually formatted using the `ChartFormat` syntax. If you use the `ChartFormat` syntax to format `ErrorBars`, for example

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

you will only format the horizontal error bars (see **Note** below).

You can get around the VBA selection problem with some ancient Excel 4 Macro (XLM):

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro ("Select(""S1EX"")") ' Select series 1 X error bars

ExecuteExcel4Macro ("Select(""S1EY"")") ' Select series 1 Y error bars
```

Aha! So select the X error bar, and format it:

```
Selection.ErrorBars.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Great! Now select the Y error bar and repeat. But the Y error bar did not change. In fact, if you do it in the opposite order, select the Y error bars first, the above line will format the X error bar despite the Y error bar being selected (also see **Note** below).

**Note** - I said that the code only formats the X error bars and not the Y error bars. What it really formats is the first set of error bars added to the chart, and I had added the X before the Y. When I reversed this and added the Y before the X, just the first error bars were formatted, the Y this time.

***Workaround 1***

Add X error bars to the series, and format them. Then duplicate the series but hide it if desired, and add Y error bars to this series and format them differently.

***Workaround 2***

Format X and Y error bars the same, using the old `Border` syntax:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars.Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

This is okay for line color, but other line formats are less flexible. For line weight, for example, you must choose among `xlHairline`, `xlThin`, `xlMedium`, and `xlThick`.